# ruby&postgres Ruby connects to database error in macOS environment

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems

this is my database.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'postgres'

conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "postgres", "postgres", "postgre")

res  = conn.exec('select tablename, tableowner from pg_tables')

res.each do |row|
    row.each do |column|
        print column
        (20-column.length).times{print " "}
    end
    puts
end
```

executable file:
*ruby database.rb*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  11: from database.rb:4:in `<main>'
  10: from database.rb:4:in `new'
   9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/postgres-compat.rb:28:in `initialize'
   8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/postgres-compat.rb:28:in `new'
   7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/connection.rb:58:in `initialize'
   6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/connection.rb:58:in `loop'
   5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/connection.rb:59:in `block in initialize'
   4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/message.rb:58:in `read'
   3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/message.rb:116:in `create'
   2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/message.rb:137:in `parse'
   1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/message.rb:82:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/postgres-pr-0.7.0/lib/postgres-pr/message.rb:139:in `block in parse': undefined method `auth_type' for #<PostgresPR::UnknownAuthType:0x0000000133830f98> (NoMethodError)
```

**What should i do next？**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the PGconn support `''` (empty string) as the options and tty value.

Have you tried setting those to nil instead:

```
PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, nil, nil, "postgres", "postgres", "postgre")
```